# Unzip with spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to listen to a directory, read in new .zip files and in the best case pass it on to a @ServiceActivator that unzips it to a directory. In the worst case i at least want to get the absolute path from the read in zip files and call the java unzip util on that path to unzip it.

Here's my InboundChannelAdapter:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "requestChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "100"))
public FileReadingMessageSource adapter() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File("path/to/zip/directory"));
    return source;
}
```

This reads in new .zips and passes them on. I already tried a small writer, that writes them to another directory, which works fine.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel" )
public boolean unzipMe() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("path/to/zip"));
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        while(ze!=null){
            String fileName = ze.getName();
            File outPut = new File("path/out/directory" + File.separator + fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPut);
            int len;
            System.out.println("output " + outPut.toString());

            while((len = zis.read(buffer))> 0){
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is my unzip method, it should get invoked by the message that comes from requestChannel, and unzip the file. At the moment i hardcoded the path to the .zip, because i can't  get to the message that arrives here. Also this implementation gives me this error, which i don't understand.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationConfiguration' defined in file [D:\Workspaces\Integrationnnn\target\classes\demo\IntegrationConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Boolean] for method match: [public static boolean java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(java.lang.String), public static java.lang.Boolean java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(boolean), public boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at demo.IntegrationnnnApplication.main(IntegrationnnnApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Boolean] for method match: [public static boolean java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(java.lang.String), public static java.lang.Boolean java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(boolean), public boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:446)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.<init>(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:37)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.ServiceActivatorAnnotationPostProcessor.createHandler(ServiceActivatorAnnotationPostProcessor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor$1.doWith(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:496)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:503)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 13 more
```

This does however reliably unzip the .zip file into the right directory, just crashes horribly afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution was to just implement my own MessageHandler and overwrite its handleMessageInternal method.